# Call a GET in a Rest Api and send POST to give informations to the Rest Api

Tags: angularjs, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm currently using Symfony with FosRestBundle to create an Api.

In symfony I would like to catch a request from the client to give back some informations. (So a get methode).

This is my code who permit the communication between the api and the client.

Api Side :

```
public function getPropertiesAction(Request $request){

    $properties = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ApiBundle:Achats')->findAll();

    if(null == $properties){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }

    $data =  findPropertiesInside($properties, $request);

    return $data;
}
```

Client side :

```
angular.module('googleMapApp')
    .service('PropertiesData', function ($http) {
        this.fetch = function(url, polygone, callback, errorCallback) {
            $http.post(url,{data: polygone}).then(callback,errorCallback);
        };
});
```

So when i do that the api return error 405 (Method Not Allowed)

[Exception from Symfomy is No route found for "POST /api/properties": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daaIL.png)

Is there a way to send post json informations from the client to the api and the api return the good properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a request body when using HTTP GET. You should pass the data in the url, either using the path or the query string.

Change your client side to $http.**get**(urlWithData).then...

Comment: My problem is my data object is a complex json, so url/data will strange isn't it ?

Comment: yes, that is a classic problem. Looking at your server code, a GET seems most suitable, because you don't change anything (e.g. no data in the db is changed). But if you have a complex search and you need to pass a lot of data to do the query (more data than a simple filter and some paging attributes), you can decide to use POST. In this case, you will need to change your server and configure your api method to accept POST. Note that your users will not be able to bookmark a specific search, and updating it by refreshing the page will be cumbersome, so carefully consider before using POST.